# Pandas: Copy a value of a row and paste it to multiple rows above in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

I need to copy the strings of `event` and paste them into three rows above and five rows down of a new column named `epoch`.

```
      event    epoch
        NaN      NaN
        NaN      NaN
        NaN      NaN
        NaN      2_1
        NaN      2_1
        NaN      2_1
        2_1      2_1
        NaN      2_1
        NaN      2_1
        NaN      2_1
        NaN      2_1
        NaN      2_1
        NaN      NaN
        NaN      NaN
        NaN      NaN
        NaN      NaN
        NaN      NaN
        NaN      3_1
        NaN      3_1
        NaN      3_1
        3_1      3_1
        NaN      3_1
        NaN      3_1
        NaN      3_1
        NaN      3_1
        NaN      3_1
        NaN      NaN
        NaN      NaN
        NaN      NaN
        NaN      NaN
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: *(considering column "epoch" doesn't exist yet)*

```
df['epoch'] = df.event.ffill(limit=5)
df['epoch'] = df['epoch'].bfill(limit=3)

df
```

Output:

| index | event | epoch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | NaN | 2_1 |
| 4 | NaN | 2_1 |
| 5 | NaN | 2_1 |
| 6 | 2_1 | 2_1 |
| 7 | NaN | 2_1 |
| 8 | NaN | 2_1 |
| 9 | NaN | 2_1 |
| 10 | NaN | 2_1 |
| 11 | NaN | 2_1 |
| 12 | NaN | NaN |
| 13 | NaN | NaN |
| 14 | NaN | NaN |
| 15 | NaN | NaN |
| 16 | NaN | NaN |
| 17 | NaN | 3_1 |
| 18 | NaN | 3_1 |
| 19 | NaN | 3_1 |
| 20 | 3_1 | 3_1 |
| 21 | NaN | 3_1 |
| 22 | NaN | 3_1 |
| 23 | NaN | 3_1 |
| 24 | NaN | 3_1 |
| 25 | NaN | 3_1 |
| 26 | NaN | NaN |
| 27 | NaN | NaN |
| 28 | NaN | NaN |
| 29 | NaN | NaN |